# Capturing iTunes traffic with Wireshark - SSL decryption question

Tags: tls, macos, ios, wireshark

I'm fooling around with Wireshark to capture the activation packets for an iPhone and some other stuff, however the traffic is encrypted. There should be a private SSL key somewhere on my computer to decrypt this traffic, but I've spent hours trying to find it with no luck. I'm on OSX Mavericks, latest iTunes build. I'd be very grateful if someone could help out.

Answer (score 4):

Cracking that tunnel is a non-trivial exercise. The short answer is that key store is located in the file `/private/var/keybags/systembag.kb` and retrieved with the kernel service called `AppleEffaceableStorage` under the locker tag `\BAG1`. This is the architecture:

[image: iPhone data protection architecture]

The keys themselves are further encrypted and checksummed using AES and HMAC. It would be a big project for you to decrypt the stream. You would be much better off finding the memory buffer where the kernel process is storing the decrypted stream and just monitoring the buffer. I think the critical process is called `keybagd` (keybag daemon). There is also a kernel extension called `AppleKeyStore` which has a subcomponent called `MobileKeyBag`. One or all of those processes will own a buffer containing the clear text traffic.

Comment: thank you, i was under the impression that it was as simple as described here http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116557

Comment: Its that simple if you have the key. The problem is getting the key out of the Mac key bag. At some point the AppleKeyStore computes the key, so if you could find the computed key in memory, that might work, but it might be hard to find that memory location. So are you going to upvote my answer or what?

Comment: @TylerDurden Both `systembag.kb` and `AppleEffaceableStorage` have nothing to do with SSL. Client-side SSL private keys and certificates are stored in Keychain, and relevant process, if you decide to dump memory, is `securityd`. Furthermore, "cracking" SSL tunnel on iOS can be as simple as installing additional root certificate. Or it might be not – depending on whether the app is doing certificate pinning. Also, I am under impression that OP asked about iTunes, not iOS.